# why does data augmentation not improve my performance (cnn)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation, conv-neural-network

I'm relatively new to deep learning. I am trying to train a CNN model to classify spectograms of EEG data. When applying data augmentation, the model performs worse than without... What am I missing? Normally our model runs with an accuracy of 0.84 and a loss of 0.5 for both training and validation.

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=0,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

datagen.fit(X_train)

model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128), validation_data= (X_test, y_test), steps_per_epoch=len(X_train) / 32, epochs=100)
```

[after training with generated data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RK04.png)

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1):

This type of data augmentation makes sense when you're dealing with actual images. A shifted or flipped image of a dog is still an image of a dog. A flipped EEG spectrogram is a completely different signal. See [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-augmentation-for-speech-recognition-e7c607482e78) for data augmentation techniques that might be applicable in your case.